# L’étiquette « idiomes » porte-t-elle bien son nom ?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Dans une question récente, j’ai pu constater que l’étiquette concernant les expressions idiomatiques était « [idiomes](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiomes) » plutôt que, par exemple, « expressions idiomatiques » ou encore « [idiotismes](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/idiotisme) » (cf. deuxième acception). Je pense qu’il s’agit d’une traduction un peu rapide de l’étiquette « *[idioms](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idioms)* » qui mérite d’être corrigée.

En effet, d’après le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/idiome) ou [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiome), un idiome est l’ensemble des moyens d’expression utilisés par une communauté. Le français est un idiome, le français de Belgique est un idiome, le français du Hainaut occidental est un idiome. Mais « tirer les vers du nez » n’est pas un idiome.

---

I recently came across the tag about idioms in a question, and saw that it was “*idiomes*” instead of, say, “*expressions idiomatiques*” or “*[idiotismes](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/idiotisme)*“ (see second acception). I believe this is an erroneous translation of the English tag “idioms” which should be corrected.

Indeed, according to the [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/idiome) or [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiome), an *idiome* is the set of ways of communications inside a given community. French is an *idiome*, the French from Belgium is an *idiome*, the French from western Hainaut is an *idiome* ; “to let the cat out of the bag” is not an *idiome* (it is, however, an English idiom).

Comment: « Idiotisme » est-il vraiment le bon terme ? En anglais, *idiom* insiste plus sur le fait que le sens d'une expression n'est pas celui de sa décomposition naïve, alors que le français *idiotisme* se réfère spécifiquement au fait que la construction ne se retrouve pas dans d'autres langues.

Comment: @Gilles « Idiotisme » n’est effectivement peut-être pas le bon terme ; je reste du moins convaincu qu’« idiome » est le mauvais.

Comment: Ceci concerne probablement également le wiki du tag *[tag:traduction]* : « Questions concernant l'équivalent français d'une expression **ou d'un idiome** en provenance d'une autre langue. »

Answer (score 4):

« Idiomes » est bien ici un anglicisme; « idiotisme » n'est pas très heureux à cause de sa proximité avec « idiot »; « expression idiomatique » est la la formule consacrée mais un peu long pour une étiquette; je proposerais donc le néologisme rare mais non ambigu « **idiomatisme** ».

---

*Idiomes* is indeed an anglicism here; *idiotisme* is odd being too close to *idiot*; *expression idiomatique* is the usual translation but somewhat verbose for a tag; I would then suggest the rare but unambiguous neologism ***idiomatisme***.

Comment: La longueur n'est pas un problème. De plus avec « expressions idiomatiques » quelqu'un qui cherche « expression » verra immédiatement que le tag existe. Je penche donc plutôt pour celui-ci.

Answer (score 3):

Après réflexion, il me semble que *idiomes* regroupe actuellement deux types de questions assez faciles à distinguer:

- Celles qui [traitent](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2521/pour-quelle-raison-il-me-court-sur-le-haricot) d'[idiotismes](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiotismes) (on peut synonymiser, voire préférer [expressions-idiomatiques](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expressions-idiomatiques)) ou qui sont à la recherche d'[équivalents](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/924/best-french-equivalent-to-two-peas-in-a-pod-equivalent-francais-de-lexpres). Il peut s'agir d'[expressions courantes](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7544/trier-sur-le-volet-de-quel-volet-sagit-il) mais aussi de [constructions étranges](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6847/is-there-an-expression-in-en-sont-on-ne-peut-plus-amoureux), de [vocabulaire culinaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1295/saignant-a-point-bien-cuit), de [locutions prépositionnelles](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2945/the-meaning-and-etymology-of-histoire-de-histoire-que), de [traits de langage](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5858/how-to-add-emphasis-as-with-i-do-or-i-did), etc. D'autres tags existent pour préciser celà.
- Celles qui sont à la recherche d'une [formulation-idiomatique](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formulation-idiomatique) : comment exprimer quelque chose en français de façon naturelle. Par exemple [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3071/how-to-translate-im-looking-for-opportunities-to-practice-my-french) ou [celle-ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2524/how-to-translate-it-serves-you-right). Certaines questions taguées *traduction* n'ont pas pour contrainte de rester fidèle à l'original, il serait mieux dans certains cas d'utiliser ce tag.

Je suggère donc que nous séparions *idiome* en deux catégories :

- [idiotismes](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiotismes)/[expressions-idiomatiques](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expressions-idiomatiques), synonymes, et
- [formulation-idiomatique](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formulation-idiomatique).

Comment: On perd toutefois l’avantage d’« expressions idiomatiques » que tu soulignait sous la réponse de jlliagre. Peut-être en faire un synonyme d’« idiotismes » ?

Comment: Oui, on peut :-)